# joomla template conversion from 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

My company updated web-site based on Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 version, and now I need to convert template to fit with the new version.

I'm following this tutorial: http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-may-2012/item/740-How-to-convert-Joomla-15-template-to-Joomla-25

I installed the converted version but there are some problems: only the header image is shown.
All the articles are hidden.

Looking the source code of the page I discovered that all the `<jdoc:include />` tags are copid in the returned HTML without being interpreted, so the components are not imported in the page.

Can you help me?

---

**UPDATE**

Turning on debug mode and error reporting an error message is shown:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessageQueue() on a non-object in /home/forup/httpdocs/jupgrade/templates/forup_25/functions.php on line 17

Comment: Most likely you have a small code error where php isn't closed or similar. Probably it is tiny and hard to see.  Start where the html in source finishes rendering correctly, comment out everything between there and the  closing tags at the bottom and then look  codeblock by codeblock. Also if you don't have error reporting on development, do that now, in case you have a php error somewhere below the header.

Comment: @Elin Unfortunately this is not my problem. I tried to use the original `index.php` file that works in 1.5 version, but in 2.5 template it doesn't work. the `include` directive gets no output...

Comment: some code would help, also any errors - do you have debug enabled and error reporting turned all the way up?

Comment: You need to show us the code that's causing the error and any template code that leads to it... otherwise it's just guesses by us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Replace: $mainframe->getMessageQueue(); 
With: JFactory::getApplication()->getMessageQueue();
```

This should help you : http://www.artisteer.com/?post_id=119930&p=forum_post&forum_id=20

Answer (score -2):

In your template php-function prints special tags of cms, like:

```
echo '<jdoc:include...'; or
print '<jdoc:include...';
```

Joomla can't process this output.

Comment: Actually Joomla! can, it parses the output from the template and replaces `<jdoc>` statements.

Comment: In joomla 2.5 <jdoc got as function result - they just showed as tags <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-14" style="none" />. Because of this, I had to change the program logic.
Really in the another way - the absence $mainframe in Joomla 2.5, but, more often, in this case displays a blank page.

Comment: QArea you are probably missing some earlier code. Compare your template to Beez and see if you are missing a step. You don't need to do echo or print, you just do the statement.